# Finding functions such that $f(x)=f(|x|)$

Tags: calculus, soft-question

I found this question in my book's "HOTS" section.

Now I can't think of any way to solve it analytically, So I tried graphically.

If $f(x)=f(|x|)$, then the graphs $y=f(x)$ and $y=f(|x|)$ will be same also. Now the graph of $y=f(|x|)$ from the graph of $y=f(x)$ is obtained by deleting the graph for negative $x-$axis and replacing it with the reflection of that for positive $x-$ axis on $y-$axis.

Using this manipulation I found following curves-

$1.$ $y=\alpha$ , $\alpha \in R$

$2.$ $y=x^n-\alpha^n$ , $\alpha \in R$, $n$ is even

$3. $ $y^2+x^2=\alpha^2$ ,  $\alpha \in R$, $y\geq 0$ or  $y\leq 0$

$4.$ $\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{\alpha^2}+\frac{y^2}{\beta^2}=1$,  $y\geq 0$ or  $y\leq 0$

$5.$ $\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{\alpha^2}-\frac{y^2}{\beta^2}=1$,  $y\geq 0$ or  $y\leq 0$

Can you help me with some other examples ?

Also how can we solve this analytically?

Comment: In one dimension, any even function satisfies this property. In higher dimensions it is not so simple.

Comment: Another example is $ f(x) = \alpha | x | + \beta $ :)

Comment: if $f$ defined in an interval of the form $(-a,a)$, then $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}(f(x)+f(-x))$ will satisfy $g(x)=g(-x)=g(|x|)$

Comment: $\cos{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Take any function at all defined for $x≥0$ and extend it to an even function on the whole line.

Comment: @K.defaoite well I don't know much about even functions but that's a good hint

Comment: @Joe yes similarly we can say $sec x$ also

Comment: @talbi did you use the property that $||x||=|x|$?

Comment: @LalitTolani: An even function satisfies $f(x)=f(-x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: @lulu , yes that solved my problem , we can take any function and replace  $ x$ with $x^2$ to get a function that satisfies given property

Comment: You don't need to take $x^2$.  If $F(x)$ is defined for $x≥0$ just let $f(x)=F(|x|)$.  Then $f(x)$ is defined for all reals and obviously passes your requirement.

Comment: @lulu yes that's also true , here we use property that  $||x||=|x|$

Comment: The correct solution in any algebra where a norm is defined (complexm quaternions, ...) is $f(x)=g(|x|)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x)=f(|x|)$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$ then the function $f$ satisfies (i) $f(x)=f(x)$ for $x\ge0$ and (ii) $f(x)=f(-x)$ for $x<0$. Since condition (i) is satisfied by any function, this boils down to $f(x)=f(-x)$ for $x<0$. And $f$ satisfies $f(x)=f(-x)$ for $x<0$ if and only if $f(x)=f(-x)$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$. Hence,
$$
\forall x\in\Bbb{R}:f(x)=f(|x|)\iff\text{$f$ is an even function defined on $\Bbb{R}$}
$$
You can read more about even functions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions). Common examples include $x^4$, $\cos(x)$, $\cosh(x)$, and $|x|$, as well as the examples you have already given in your question.

Comment: By the way, in complex field $x^4$ is not the same thing that $|x|^4$. Is it correct?

Comment: @giorgiomugnaini: Yes, in general, $x^4\neq|x^4|$. Consider the case $x=1+i$.

Comment: @Joe yes that correctly answers my question, thanks for your help

Comment: No problem, @LalitTolani! Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 2):

Although "$f(x)$ is an even function" may seem the acceptable solution, it can not be the correct answer to the question, without further hypotheses.

For example, if we take:

$$f(x)=x^2$$

that is an even function *i.e.* we have $f(x)=-f(-x)$, we have in the complex plane

$$f(i)=-1 \ne f(|i|)=1$$

So the the requirement $f(x)=f(|x|)$ is not satisfied, for the even function $x^2$.

Instead, any function $f(x)$ of the form $f(x)=g(|x|)$ where $g(u)$ is generic function, satisfies $f(x)=f(|x|)$, because of the identity $||x||=|x|$.

This solution: $f(x)=g(|x|)$ is valid also in complex field. Moreover, it is valid in any algebra where norm is defined (quaternions, octonions,...).

Examples:

$$f(x)=|x|^2$$

$$f(x)=\sin(|x|)$$

$$f(x)=\dfrac{1}{|x|}$$

$$f(x)=\dfrac{\exp(-|x|)}{|x|}$$

$$f(x)=a_0+a_1|x|+a_2|x|^2+...$$

Comment: why downvote? incomprehensible...

Comment: This is a good answer and addresses the main point, these downvoters should have at least commented their issue. (+1 from me)